# Fundamental polygon of the pair of pants

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a set of notes on Representations of Surface Groups made for a workshop at AIM.

It states that a genus g surface with $k$ holes has a decomposition (I am assuming this is referring to that surface's fundamental domain) as a $4g+k$-gon with $2g$-side identifications.

As far as I understand, I can treat a pair of pants as having three-holes, in which case its fundamental domain should be a $4(0) +3=3$-gon, i.e. a triangle.

However, the fundamental domain of a pair of pants (from what I have seen) is a hexagon and not a triangle.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Hint: Pair of pants has 3 boundary components.

Comment: I thought a pair of pants has $a $boundaries and $b$ punctures such that  $a+b=3$.

Comment: One thing you should clear up: What do *you* mean by a genus $g$ surface with $k$ holes? Do you mean it has $k$ boundaries? Or $k$ punctures? Or either or both or some mix?

Comment: That is also not clear to me. The note states genus g with k-holes, there is no further explanation. With that said, when is it appropriate to consider both boundaries and punctures on the same footing?